# how can I create an incidence matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a incidence matrix using R.
I have a file with 3 column, like:

```
#   id  x   y
# 1  A 22   2
# 2  B  4  21
# 3  C 21 360
# 4  D 26   2
# 5  E 22  58
# 6  F  2 347
```

And I want a matrix like (without col and row names):

```
#   2 4 21 22 26 58 347 360
# A 1 0  0  1  0  0   0   0
# B 0 1  1  0  0  0   0   0
# C 0 0  1  0  0  0   0   1
# D 0 1  0  0  1  0   0   0
# E 0 0  0  1  0  1   0   0
# F 1 0  0  0  0  0   1   0
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                      x = c(22L, 4L, 21L, 26L, 22L, 2L),
                      y = c(2L, 21L, 360L, 2L, 58L, 347L)),
                 .Names = c("id", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Does your matrix's first column start with a letter?

Comment: yes, 
In the original file the first column is a name

Comment: In your expected output, row `D` col `2` should have value `1` instead of `0`, and row `D` col `4` should have `0` instead of `1`. Rest are correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right Sowmya. 
My mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `melt` the dataset and try with `table`

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(df1, id.var="id")[-2])
```

Or using only `base R`

```
table(df1$id[row(df1[-1])], unlist(df1[-1]))
#    2 4 21 22 26 58 347 360
#  A 1 0  0  1  0  0   0   0
#  B 0 1  1  0  0  0   0   0
#  C 0 0  1  0  0  0   0   1
#  D 1 0  0  0  1  0   0   0
#  E 0 0  0  1  0  1   0   0
#  F 1 0  0  0  0  0   1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `cbind.data.frame()` along with `table()` function

```
> table(cbind.data.frame(ID=df1$id,Result=c(df1$x,df1$y)))
             Result
  ID  2 4 21 22 26 58 347 360
   A  1 0  0  1  0  0   0   0
   B  0 1  1  0  0  0   0   0
   C  0 0  1  0  0  0   0   1
   D  1 0  0  0  1  0   0   0
   E  0 0  0  1  0  1   0   0
   F  1 0  0  0  0  0   1   0
```

Comment: What about to do this in Julia?
Do you also work with this language ?
Thank you!

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior Nope. I have never worked on that language.